# SQL Combine Rows Into One Row Using Union and Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

[image]

[image]

I would like to ask help regarding my query. I would like to get a result like shown in my image. I like to use `GROUP BY` with `UNION` but can't get the result I want.

Here's my sample query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         '' as AccomplishmentDate, ETRDate, ProjectName, EquipmentName, 
         0 as AccomplishmentActualHour, ETRActualHour 
     FROM 
         Table1

     UNION

     SELECT 
         AccomplishmentDate, '' AS ETRDate, ProjectName, EquipmentName,
         AccomplishmentActualHour, 0 AS ETRActualHour 
     FROM 
         Table1) AS Transaction
```

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can use `MAX` function and `GROUP BY` to make it

```
SELECT 
       MAX(AccomplishmentDate),
       MAX(ETRDate),
       ProjectName,
       EquipmentName,
       MAX(AccomplishmentActualHour),
       MAX(ETRActualHour) 
FROM
(
   SELECT NULL as AccomplishmentDate, ETRDate, ProjectName,EquipmentName, 0 as 
        AccomplishmentActualHour, ETRActualHour 
   FROM T
   UNION
   SELECT AccomplishmentDate, NULL as ETRDate, ProjectName,EquipmentName,
        AccomplishmentActualHour,0 as ETRActualHour 
   FROM T
) t
GROUP BY  
     ProjectName,EquipmentName
```

sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/337ff/2

From your image data, you seem this can be work.

```
SELECT MAX(AccomplishmentDate),
       MAX(ETRDate),
       ProjectName,
       EquipmentName,
       MAX(AccomplishmentActualHour),
       MAX(ETRActualHour)
FROM Table1
GROUP BY  ProjectName,EquipmentName
```

**EDIT**

You need to write subquery to make a `ROW_NUMBER` then add `GROUP BY` and `MAX`

```
;WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT NULL as AccomplishmentDate, ETRDate, ProjectName,EquipmentName, 0 as 
          AccomplishmentActualHour, ETRActualHour,1 grp
   FROM T
   UNION
   SELECT AccomplishmentDate, NULL as ETRDate, ProjectName,EquipmentName,
          AccomplishmentActualHour,0 as ETRActualHour,2
   FROM T
),grpCTE AS(
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY grp) rn
FROM CTE
)
SELECT MAX(AccomplishmentDate),
       MAX(ETRDate),
       ProjectName,
       EquipmentName,
       MAX(AccomplishmentActualHour),
       MAX(ETRActualHour) 
FROM grpCTE
group by 
        ProjectName,
       EquipmentName,
       rn
```

sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/43f3c/25

by the way if you have new question you can create a new thread :)

Comment: Wow..It works..Thank you so much my friend..it really helps.

Comment: No problem you can mark this answer if that help you

Comment: @a16tintin, if someone gives you an answer that solves your problem, then accept the answer (and upvote.)

Comment: @jarlh Oh okey.Thanks:)

Comment: @D-Shih new problem occurs. Im not going to use MAX because I need  to show unique rows. for example if accomplishment date is different I need to add new row for this. Not going to get the MAX of Accomplishment Date.:(.What should I do?

Comment: @a16tintin You need to make a `rownumber` on the result set then `group by` and `MAX` you can see my edit answer.

Comment: @a16tintin  By the way if you have new question you can create a new thread :)